# redirection doesn't work in jquery script

Tags: jquery

I'm using a simple script to submit a form , and after the form is submited , it should be redirected to another page

it was working till jquery 1.4.4 came out

any idea how to fix this ?!

```
                $(location).attr('href',redir);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `$(location).attr("href", redir)` do this `window.location.href = redir`
this will redirect the page like you expect

Comment: funny cause i checked $(window.location).attr('href' ....  but the one you said worked gently

Answer (score 0):

Use simple Javascript

`self.location="www.sample.com";`